# How do I access file outside of 'resources', but still in WAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, war

I am adding a static XSD file to my application WAR, but cannot get it into the 'resources'. I can live with that, however I cannot seem to access the file using FileSystemResource.
The file resides under the WAR as 'tools/schema/model.xsd'. I have been trying variations of the below but it does not work.

```
    new FileSystemResource("/tools/schema/model.xsd");
    new FileSystemResource("tools/schema/model.xsd");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled, you don't need to have a resources-directory in your war. if you use the maven war-plugin everything out of the src/resources directory will be put into /WEB-INF/classes and is accessible via .getResource() called on an arbitrary class that is contained in your WAR.

If you want additional resources there, then you can use the maven-resource-plugin to copy it first into classes so that the war-plugin puts it correctly into your WAR. 
say MyClass is a Java-Class inside your WAR

```
 MyClass.getResource("'tools/schema/model.xsd")
```

should return the URL or getResourceAsStream returns an InputStream that directly can be read.